# ignore directories in the find command

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, find

How do I just ignore the directories in the find command

```
find /testfile1

/testfile1
/testfile1/tmp1.txt
/testfile1/tmp2.txt
/testfile1/tmp3.txt
/testfile1/tmp4.txt
/testfile1/test1
/testfile1/test1/as
/testfile1/test1/dw
/testfile1/test2
/testfile1/test2/adsad
/testfile1/test2/bc
```

/testfile1 , /testfile1/test1 and /testfile1/test2 are the directories. So I want to remove those directories in the result and I cant use type -f since I need to get the full path for the files.

so how would I just get the files with the full path like

```
/testfile1/tmp1.txt
/testfile1/tmp2.txt
/testfile1/tmp3.txt
/testfile1/tmp4.txt
/testfile1/test1/as
/testfile1/test1/dw
/testfile1/test2/adsad
/testfile1/test2/bc
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To exclude just directories:

```
find /testfile1 ! -type d
```

This will include symlinks and assorted other non-regular files.

Comment: Thanks. Why didn't I thought about that :)

Comment: Some shells may interpret the `!` as a request to search your command history.  I recommend `find /testfile1 -not -type d` instead.

Comment: @AdamKatz That is true. Changed it.

Comment: @Wintermute Readability is always debatable, but otherwise `!` should always be preferred. It is posix, `-not` isn't. I also don't know of any shells that treat ` ! ` as a command history expansion (and you could escape it if some did)

Comment: @AdamKatz Which shells treat ` ! ` argument as history expansion?

Comment: @BroSlow Oh, you're right. There appears to be a translation error in the German version of the `find` man page (it states that `-not` is POSIX-conforming while `!` is not), but the English man page and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html agree with you. Back we go, then.

Comment: @BroSlow hm, I stand corrected.  I didn't know `-not` was not POSIX compliant, and `zsh` (which is the shell I had in mind) only queries the event history when the `!` is followed by a nonspace character, so this usage should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
-type f
```

as a test, will only return regular files

Comment: I think this is worth a downvote as the question specifically says he can't use `-type f`.